# Polar set of $S=\{s\in\mathbb{R}^n:1^Ts≤1,\; s≥0\}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The definition of a polar set, that I am working with, is: $M^{pol}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:m^Tx≤1, \forall m\in M\} $
Now I want to find the polar $S^{pol}$ of $S$, where $S=\{s\in\mathbb{R}^n:$**1**$^Ts≤1,\; s≥0\}$
S is the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for which each $s_i$ is bigger than $0$ and for which the sum of all $s_i$ is smaller than $1$. Would then $S^{pol}$ be all vectors $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that **1**$^Tx≤1$? Therefore: $S^{pol}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:$**1**$^Tx≤1\}$
I don't think my answer is wrong but I feel it may be incomplete and I am unsure how to prove that for $x$ with **1**$^Tx>1:$ $s^Tx>1$, therefore I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: Your answer is wrong: let $n=2$ and take $x=(-1,2)$ for which $1^Tx\le 1$ but $x$ is not in $S^{pol}$ because for $s=(0,1)\in S$ we have $s^Tx=2$.

Comment: @Ahmad you're right, thank you! Do you have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: The biggest set that I have found so far to be inside $S^{pol}$ is $\{x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \, | \, \|x_+\|_1\le 1\}$, where $x_+=\max(x,0)$ componnetwise. Why: $s^Tx=s^T(x_+-x_-)=s^Tx_+-s^Tx_-\le s^Tx_+\le \|x_+\|_1\le 1,$ where $x_-=\max(-x,0)$ also componentwise and $s\ge 0$ and $1^Ts\le 1$. I still cannot show the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S^{pol}=U:=\{u\in \mathbb R^n \ | \ \max_{u_i\ge 0} u_i\le 1\}$ for $S=\{s\in \mathbb R^n \ | \ 1^Ts \le 1\text{ and } s\ge 0\}$:

(1) $U\subseteq S^{pol}:\quad$
let $u\in U$ and $s\in S$, then by defining $u_+:=\max(u,0)$ and $u_-:=\max(-u,0)$; both componentwise, we have:
$$u^Ts=(u_+-u_-)^Ts=u_+^Ts-u_-^Ts\le u_+^Ts=\sum_{u_i\ge 0}u_is_i\le \Big(\max_{u_i\ge 0} u_i\Big)\sum_i s_i\le \max_{u_i\ge 0}u_i\le 1.$$ 
Thus, $u\in S^{pol}$.

(2) $S^{pol}\subseteq U: \quad$
let $p\in S^{pol}$, and $i^*\in argmax_{p_i\ge 0} \ p_i$, then choose $s=\textbf{e}_{i^*}\in \mathbb R^n.$ We see that $s\in S$ and $s^Tp=\max_{p_i\ge 0} p_i\le 1$. Hence, $p\in U$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Is it necessary to say $U=\{u\in \mathbb R^n \ | \ \max_{u_i\ge 0} u_i\le 1\}$ or would $U=\{u\in \mathbb R^n \ | \ \max u_i\le 1\}$ suffice? Since taking the max of all $u_i$, including negative values, would to my understanding still give $U=S^{pol}$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Either way! You’re welcome.